# Import first excel worksheet to access where the worksheet name changes

Tags: excel-2010, ms-access-2010

I have excel data that I want imported into MS Access. The excel data is always on the first worksheet of the excel file. However, the name of the worksheet is constantly changing. The worksheet name is not predictable, as it is basically the last date someone updated it on. This could be the current date or several days earlier.

I want to set up a linked table that wont stop working when the name of the worksheet is changed. Is this possible to accomplish without getting too complicated?

Comment: I havent linked a table before, but most of the excel libraries for different programs lets you access the sheet by the index number and name. There has to be some method to access it by the index

Comment: How does the name change? By date, by some variable? Is it the most recent file in some folder? Please edit your question to include some detail.

Comment: I am familiar with linked tables and fairly comfortable with using VBA, but I'd say I have plenty left to learn. I was hoping the solution would be somewhat simple, but everything I've tried results in an error so far.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include code for some of your tests.

Comment: I attempted to use a dynamic named range, as new lines of data are added when the worksheet is updated. However, the dynamic named range does not appear when using the import wizard.

Comment: I had it working using a named range that selected the entire column of each field I was interested in, but the named range was lost when the user updated excel. 

There must be an easier way. If I could just figure out how to return the name of the first worksheet, I could import it using VBA.